# Page Access Token Expiration Doesn't Match Official Documentation

Tags: facebook-graph-api, migration, facebook-access-token

I'm seeing inconsistencies between Facebook' stated policy regarding the expiration time of Page access tokens, and the expiration time for tokens obtained through my application.

According to https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/ regarding the new access token policies effective July 5th:

> "When a user grants an app the manage_pages permission, the app is able to obtain page access tokens for pages that the user administers by querying the [User ID]/accounts Graph API endpoint. With the migration enabled, when using a short-lived user access token to query this endpoint, the page access tokens obtained are short-lived as well.
>
> Exchange the short-lived user access token for a long-lived access token using the endpoint and steps explained earlier. **By using a long-lived user access token, querying the [User ID]/accounts endpoint will now provide page access tokens that do not expire for pages that a user manages.**"

In my authentication flow, I retrieve a 2 month token along with the `manage_pages` permission (migration is enabled). I then use this token to request Page access tokens via the `[User ID]/accounts` endpoint. The Page access token I'm getting back are shown to expire in 2 months according to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug. Facebook's policy (above) seems to state that these tokens should never expire.

Can someone help explain what's going on?

Comment: I have the exact same problem.  I acquire a short-lived user access token.  Then, I convert that token into an extended (long-lived) user access token.  Using this token, I acquire page access tokens.  These page access tokens, contrary to Facebook's documentation, expire in 60 days.  Having non-expiring page access tokens is essential for our app... Thanks for creating this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the community agrees that this is a bug.  View the Facebook bug page at: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/461517520524921